# Gulp sass errors silently

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I am trying to use `gulp-sass` to compile my scss files, but for some reason it is failing but not displaying an error message.

This is the command output for `gulp styles`:

```
[20:40:04] Requiring external module babel-core/register
[20:40:05] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\Development\Web Applications\webux\webux2\gulpfile.babel.js
[20:40:05] Starting 'styles'...
```

Here is my gulp task:

```
gulp.task('styles', () => {
  return gulp.src('app/styles/*.scss')
    .pipe($.sass.sync({
      outputStyle: 'expanded',
      precision: 10,
      includePaths: ['.']
    }).on('error', err => {
      $.util.log(err);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/styles'));
});
```

I get the same output when using `$.sass.logError` as the error callback.

Comment: I have the same issue on Windows 7. Did you found any solution ?

Comment: Nope I haven't, I re-did it using webpack which works great